# Polynomials and division algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

How can I use division algorithm to solve this question?

Comment: A duplicate of [this freshly deleted question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1042751/11619). I'm not sure what to think about this? (That link works only for 10k+ users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: if the leading coefficient of $f$ is a unit, you can apply the standard polynomial division algorithm to calculate $g/f$ with remainder in $R[x]$. This is a straightforward generalization of a similar fact for polynomial rings over fields.

Comment: @user26857: if we have an algorithm (deterministic procedure), the uniqueness is obvious.

Comment: @user26857: $r$ has smaller degree than $f$, but on the other hand there is a polynomial $h\in S[x]$ such that $fh=g$. Then $f(h-q)=r$. Since the leading coefficient of $f$ is a unit (so not a zero divisor), it follows that $f(h-q)$ is zero or of degree at least equal to degree of $f$.

Comment: @user26857: and uniqueness is obvious, because we have a deterministic procedure which we follow. The result of a deterministic procedure (if it terminates) is determined by what we start with. For multivariate polynomials the procedure is not so obvious (as we don't know which coefficient we're supposed to match), though if I recall correctly it can still be made deterministic using Grobner bases or something of the sort, but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more tedious way:

Let $g = f \cdot d$, where $g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n_g} g_k x^k$, $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n_f} f_k x^k$ and $d(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n_d} d_k x^k$.
This gives $g_k = \sum_{i=\max(k-n_g,0)}^{\min(k,n_f)} f_{i} d_{k-i}$, for $k \in \{ 0,...,n_f+n_d \}$.

We have $g_k, f_k \in R$, and $d_k \in S$.

For $k \ge n_f$ we have $g_k = f_{n_f} d_{k-n_f}+\sum_{i=\max(k-n_d,0)}^{n_f-1} f_{i} d_{k-i}$, where the 'empty' sum is taken to be $0$.

This gives $g_{n_f+n_d} = f_{n_f} d_{n_d}$,  hence $d_{n_d} \in R$ since
$f_{n_f}$ is a unit in $R$.

Now suppose $d_i \in R$ for $i\in \{n_d-l+1,...,n_d\}$, then
$g_{n_f+n_d-l}  = f_{n_f} d_{n_d-l}+\sum_{i=\max(n_f-l,0)}^{n_f-1} f_{i} d_{n_f+n_d-l-i}$ and since $n_f+n_d-l-i \ge n_d-l+1 $, we see that
$f_{n_f} d_{n_d-l} = g_{n_f+n_d-l} - \sum_{i=\max(n_f-l,0)}^{n_f-1} f_{i} d_{n_f+n_d-l-i} \in R$, and since $f_{n_f}$ is a unit in $R$, we
see that $d_{n_d-l} \in R$.